# c++ passing template params

Tags: c++, templates

Two templates:

```
template <int var>
struct Yellow
{
    int name;
    double list[var];
};

template <int var>
struct Red
{
    int name;
    Yellow<var> yel;
};
```

Where we are providing the size of the array list.

How do I pass this to a function?
e.g.

```
bool foo(Red<int> red) { return true; }
```

As this gives 'type name is not allowed'

Comment: Darn. I was attempting to provide a generic data structure whereby I could make variants with different array sizes. Is there a better way? (I have to use fixed size arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use a type template type parameter when instantiating these structures, you use an integer literal, like

```
Red<10> red;
```

Comment: Hmm. seems what I was attempting is not possible.

Comment: I have to use fixed arrays on my system. I wanted to provide a generic structure where by the size of the array could be defined.

Perhaps there is another way?

Comment: @def The only generic structure in C++ where the size can be determined run-time is `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an int template parameter:

```
template <int N>
//        ^^^^^
bool foo(Red<N> red) { return true; }
//           ^
```